# My nav button does not expand and reveal navigation buttons

Tags: html, nav

My nav button does not expand to reveal navigation buttons as supposed to.
Here is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Restorant Con fusion</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
```

Here is the start of the block that is not working:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-        toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-  controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Restorante Con Fusion</a>

    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the end of the problematic block.

```
<header class="jumbotron">

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <h3 align=center>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
            <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
            <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
            <p><a  href="#">More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <h3 align=center>This Month's Promotions</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
            <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
            <p><a href="#">More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <h3 align=center>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
            <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
            <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
            <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
            <p><a href="#">More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="row-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sx-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h5>Links</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                <h5>Our Address</h5>
                <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                    <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a>
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
                    <a href="mailto:">Mail</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                <p align=center>Â© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.mim.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you might have a typo in the url for your jquery script. Instead of `min.js`, it says `mim.js`.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues:

1) You have a typo in your include of jQuery: `jquery.mim.js`

2) make sure your `data-toggle="collapse"` on your dropdown button doesn't have a big white space like your example does.

eg: `data-        toggle="collapse"`

Make these changes and everything should work as long as your bootstrap css and js is loading correctly.

To test the dropdown nav make sure you reduce the size of your browser window to mobile size and you see the 'hamburger' menu icon.